# Calling parent controller method from directives in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a situation where i want to call a parent controller method from a directive on ng-change. The call to controller method never triggers, not sure what could be wrong.
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

**Sample Code:**

```
<body ng-app="content-app" ng-controller="ParentController">
    <div header-menu report-manager="model"></div>
</body>
```

report-manager is a model.

**Header-Menu Directive:**

```
var $module = angular.module('content-app');

    $module.directive('headerMenu', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            scope: {
                reportManager: '='
            },
            templateUrl: '/scripts/app/directives/header-menu.template.htm'
        };
    });
```

**header-menu.template.htm**

```
<div>
  <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="filter in filters" ng-controller="ChildController" ng-change="method()" />
  </ul>
</div>
```

**ParentController.**

```
angular.module('content-app')
.controller("MainController", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.method = function () { // do something };
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Method needs to be passed into directive with `"&"`, you can pass functions with "&"

```
$module.directive('headerMenu', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            reportManager: '=',
            method: "&" // needs to be passed into the headerMenu directive
        },
        templateUrl: '/scripts/app/directives/header-menu.template.htm',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            scope.makeChange = function(){
                scope.method();
            }
        }
    };
});
```

HTML:

```
<div header-menu method="method()" report-manager="model"></div>
```

and

```
 <li ng-repeat="filter in filters" ng-controller="ChildController" ng-change="makeChange()" />
```